# [tag:example] syntax not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, markdown, markdown-rendering

This seems to be broken across SE. For instance [this recent meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76237/will-so-have-a-big-issue-in-x-years-time-with-a-mass-of-now-incorrect-answers/76241#76241) and [this one on Ask Ubuntu meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/250/866).

In places where it "already was" the formatting continues. ([Example](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/184/tag-synonym-suggestions/847#847))

Here's the shortest-distance example of this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: [Shorter example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/76244#76244)

Comment: (As for *In places where it "already was" the formatting continues* —that is probably because [the magic is done when a post is saved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482).)

Comment: @Kevin Did you mark this completed *just* before you pushed the fix, or is the addition of the [status-completed] not trigger it in the same vein that tag edits don't count as question body edits?

Comment: @Grace - tag edits don't re-render the post body.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed*.

If you come across any affected posts, give them a trivial edit (add a space or something) to force a re-render.

<sub>*On everything but SO, which will get the fix tonight once traffic falls off.</sub>