# Looking for concise guide on what to do with obsolete answers

Tags: feature-request, support

I'm looking for clear, concise guidelines on what to do when one comes across an answer (written by another user, and not necessarily the accepted answer, or one with high votes) that is now unambiguously obsolete (e.g., an answer that depends on an officially discontinued feature.)<sup>1</sup>.

- If such guidelines exist, apologies for my inability to find them; I'd appreciate a pointer.<sup>2</sup>
- If they don't, I can't think of a more fitting way celebrate SE's [10m questions milestone](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) than to put up such guidelines.

---

<sup>1</sup> IOW, I'm not referring answers that have become obsolete in the sense that a better solution now exists.  This second form of obsolescence is also problematic, but I imagine it's much harder to come up with a good policy about it.

<sup>2</sup>When I search for what to do about obsolete answers in SE sites, I find [lengthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/167367) [threads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/167367) on the subject, but it's hard for me to glean from them clear, concise guidelines.  Neither can I find such guidelines in the [SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Obsolete answers in general, or ones that you have written?

Comment: @HDE226868: Sorry, I meant strictly answers written by others.  I'll update my post to make this clear.

Comment: There's very rarely such a thing as an obsolete answer at all; if you're asking about the technical sites (I notice you're most active on SO) There'll always be someone using an older version of some software. Please don't force your own preconceptions of what's "current" on others.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: OMG, you are right!  Poor things...  What was I thinking!?

Comment: I'm not sure how sarcasm helps the argument (though I do appreciate it - being British). I've answered questions for people who know what tech they _should_ be using but are stuck due to their clients when what they're using left extended support over 20 years ago. This was recently.

Comment: Over at Arqade, we've recently had a discussion on this issue. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/updating-an-out-of-date-answer-versus-keeping-author-intent/10768#10768

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concise guide on what to do with obsolete answers. You should do what you would do with any answer which doesn't offer a viable solution to the question.

1. **Downvote**, to give a signal to future readers that answer isn't worth their time.
2. If you're so inclined, **leave a comment** to alert the author and any future readers that the solution no longer works and why. The author *may* come back and delete their obsolete answer or modify it so it's no longer obsolete.
3. **Answer** with a non-obsolete solution. Admittedly, this may not be possible, especially if someone has already done so with the solution you would offer.

There is [an effort afoot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/) to make a formal process within the system, but it's obviously at least 6-8 weeks away from being implemented after a methodology is settled on.

A lot of the time, an obsolete answer is okay. Some people aren't willing (or able) to upgrade to the latest library/version/widget/etc.

See also:

- [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705)
- [What to do about deprecated questions & answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115320)
- [Will SO have a big issue in 'x' years time with a mass of now incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76237)
- [How can the policy regarding incorrect obsolete answers be improved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149706)
- [Edit old answer and obsolete methods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146115)