# Q&A with accurate info, but it has become obsolete

Tags: discussion, feature-request, obsolete-information

Sometimes I run into answers that may have been correct at the time of answer, but could be wrong today. I ran into this more obvious post today, [Mono on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377116/mono-on-the-iphone) which says "there is no way to develop iOS from .NET" which is wrong today.

How do we/I handle this kind of answers?

In this case, answerers just put an answer or comment telling the latest news, which will be fine overall. The drawbacks is that the accepted marks on answers that aren't correct, and also that comments and answers afterwords may lead to poor answer quality because nobody (or few) monitor the question. I would see a alternate Flag that marks the question as Obsolete, old or maybe reviewing it like a sort of wiki where answerers/askers edit the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with obsolete answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the best things you can do with obsolete answers:

- edit the answer yourself to include more relevant, up to date information
- flag such questions for moderator attention; I cleaned up the example you gave.

Leaving comments is sufficient, but I think taking action yourself, or kicking it up to a moderator, will provide the best results.

Comment: This would be a functional task. It does, how I look at it, still leave some drawbacks. 1. You edited the question but the answers remain updated for the original question (which let answer appear desultorily). 2. Who got / feel worth against no points for editing and updating. Most important 3. Who was supervised my (or someones) edits (due to 2, who cares much in doing it). **Clean up flag**  should be the way to do it, if not a new functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Questions and answers are all timestamped and have revision history so you can see the exact age of any of the information.

Also, this is somewhat answered in [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

Comment: Your right about timestamped answer. My point is handling of the information, not check it's age. If I got a x year old answer says "No, you should use ASMX", would I understand that same question gives today would say "ASMX is out, try WCF if your new to the subject". Your link seems precious and very much a potential duplicate to this, thanks!