# Pointing out use of deprecated code: edit, comment, new answer or nothing?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)
>   [What to do about deprecated questions & answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115320/what-to-do-about-deprecated-questions-answers)

If an answer for an older question uses now deprecated functions from an API, what is the preferred way to handle the situation?

I had some suggested edits accepted, but certain individuals voted to rejected them, even though they [modified the answers in a consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/217048) and [non-destructive manner](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/217055).

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115320/what-to-do-about-deprecated-questions-answers) covers the same ground but there doesn't seem to be a consensus.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions here, can you distill it to just one? (As an aside, I reject a lot of edits too: *approved 506 edit suggestions, and rejected 271 edit suggestions.* Doesn't look like he's completely out of line.)

Comment: Good point, reduced it.

Comment: Why do you reject so many edits? Are you against the idea of community editing, or is that simply a reasonable indication of how many bad edits there are? The proportion of accept/reject seems highly variable amongst users. People are all different of course, but does it indicate two camps regarding edits being generally a good or bad thing? Or from the side of edit reviewers do you have a choice which edits you review, so maybe you choose the crappy ones?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to deal with obsolete answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/147650)

Comment: @Sean: a lot of rejections are for edits when they should have commented/answered. The other big chunk are when people just plain fail at editing (language issues often). The final bits are usually improper code changes, vandalism, awful tag wikis, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the way you edit things, but I still think that the new answer is the best solution. It adds no noise into the original answer, and you can get some extra reputation!

Comment: +1. Also add a comment on the older, out of date, answer

Comment: thanks, I will go with this in future (new answer + comment on old answer). If the original answerer wants to they can then update their question.

Answer (score 2):

I typically will preserve the original answer and append the new content with an **UPDATE** label in the text. I have seen too many edits that made subsequent answers or comments meaningless.  Also, deprecated APIs live forever, and I find some value in seeing "this is how we did in in 2009, and this is how we do it now in 2012."  Some poor sod is going to find those deprecated API calls in somebody's legacy code, after all.

---

**UPDATE**: I just use a boldface **UPDATE** in the text of the addendum to the original answer.  I do not use an `update` tag, and believe an `update` tag would be harmful.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but is an update label a tag? Like my original question here is tagged as Discussion?

Comment: @Sean, an update label is not a tag.  I've updated my answer.