# Should outdated "Related" questions be edited to address the overarching problem?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, old-questions

I mainly contribute to ProWebmasters - Google changes all the time and I and notice a ton of questions that the correct answer to which is no longer relevant.

I come across a ton of very old "Related" questions and either the way we handle the problem has changed, the question is about something that is deprecated yet replaced, or there is no way to answer the question without asking a question.

What is the best policy here? I'm thinking it makes logical sense to edit the post saying something like:

**Revised to include up-to-date information on the topic for users facing similar problems, rather than a verbatim answer**

Otherwise, if I answer the question *without a direct answer* I risk comments saying "this doesn't answer the question".

As a noob, any/all advice is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Related" questions? The ones that are linked in the sidebar?

Comment: Yeah, the ones linked in the sidebar.

Comment: How is this related to the fact that they are linked in the sidebar? It seems the core problem is just that there are old questions with outdated answers.

Comment: Yes, that is the core problem. I am asking: should those be edited with a message like I describe in bold in my question, or should they be marked as closed?

Comment: In that case, does this answer your question? [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outdated Answers project kicking off on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361097/282094) and answer:    https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11706/282094

Comment: I would welcome a discussion about this issue on https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/   If there are classes of questions that have outdated answers or specific questions that need some help, we can work as a community to clean them up.  You are also welcome to write new direct answers to questions where the other answers are outdated and include lots of additional updated information as well.