# Aging questions

Tags: discussion

How do we/can we deal with "aging" questions?

For example

- They become irrelevant
- An answer that was accepted 10 years ago is maybe not an answer any longer or it could become a less preferrable one
- Links do not work any longer
- Software used as part of a solution is not any longer maintained
- Concepts becomes deprecated
- New technologies evolve that deprecate previously used solution models

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361097/outdated-answers-project-kicking-off-on-stack-overflow probably worth a look / related

Comment: It's worth noting that ancient unnoticed duplicates turn-up from time to time and a few simply off-topic ones because the site's meta arrangements changed over time - main meta used to be SO meta.

Answer (score 2):

If a question is no longer useful then, unless both it and any answer(s) can be edited to make them once again useful, I think your best option may be to simply downvote it and/or any answer(s) that you also think are no longer useful.