# How can I mark a question with an out-of-date answer?

Tags: feature-request, bump, outdated-information

Maybe I'm missing something but an example would be this question about rails:

[Rails validation over redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536428/rails-validation-over-redirect)

with the selected answer from 2009.

I'm sure there's now a better way to do this, is there a way to bump it?

Comment: This post deals with unanswered questions - but the methods can apply to your case as well - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you're looking for an updated answer, you can:**

- Edit the post to improve it in some, ever-so-slight, way. This will bump it to the home page for a while so people can look at it. However, this is highly inefficient since it doesn't necessarily tell people that the answers need updated. It still appears as an answered and accepted question and it's probably unlikely to draw on a lot of additional viewers. It does cover the "bumping" part though.
- Add a bounty to the question. In the information box, explain that the answer is outdated and you are looking for a more recent answer. It may take a bit to get an answer, but you'll likely get one. Sure, this costs reputation, so you'd probably only do this if you *really* wanted the answer. If you don't need an updated answer, why bother? Someone who wants it will add a bounty eventually.
- Ask around in chat or other places to find people who might be willing to update it. A little work can go a long way!

**If you have an updated answer, you can:**

Just post it as an answer. If it's dramatically different from an existing answer, it's unlikely that you'll be able to edit it into something. Also, posting a new answer bumps the question to the home page as well, so any visitors who do end up viewing the question will spot your new answer and vote on it accordingly.

If it's a minor change such as a version number, you can just edit it directly into the post or add a comment to the post so that visitors can see that note.

---

You [shouldn't downvote old, outdated answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117379/should-outdated-answers-be-voted-down) though.

Answer (score 3):

Update the old answer and add a comment

"No longer valid post release *X.Y*."

Then write the new answer, and include a comment such as,

"Note: This applies to releases *X.Y* and forward."

(Thanks to commenters who pointed out to me that a downvote is not correct!)

Comment: I don't think we need to down-vote the old answer.

Comment: @Scott: You should read [Should outdated answers be voted down?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117379/should-outdated-answers-be-voted-down)

Comment: I'll _upvote_ the old answer, if it is otherwise useful; legacy maintenance comes to us all.

Comment: @animuson ammended to remove the downvote recommendation.