# Should previously correct answers be downvoted?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)
>   [Should outdated answers be voted down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117379/should-outdated-answers-be-voted-down)

Some answers were correct at the time they were posted, but became outdated (quite often due to an API change.) Should those answers be downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps just leave a comment with that very explanation instead?

Comment: Why would you down-vote outdated answers?  Why should the person who wrote the answer lose points just because the answer is old?

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to *edit* such answers and update/correct them.

At the least, a comment that explains they are outdated (and why) would be warranted and at least allow the OP to update and correct it themselves.

Comment: Not sure about that. I don't think you're supposed to change the actual content of an answer.

Comment: @lunboks - If it were not allowed, it would not be possible.

Comment: Tons of things are possible and not allowed, like sockpuppet voting or vandalism. Updating stuff is more of a gray area IMO.

Comment: @lunboks - Updating stuff was always one of the things that was allowed and _wanted_. Jeff always said that answers should become the best they could be and it doesn't matter if the OP did that or if they had help.