# reasking outdated questions?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

I was looking over the subject of unit testing and found this 4 year old topic.

[NUnit vs Visual Studio 2008's Test Projects for Unit Testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92869/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2008s-test-projects-for-unit-testing)

I want to get some updated information.

Should I open nunit-vs-visual-studio-2012s-test-projects-for-unit-testing topic?

I considered offering bounty but seems that the topic there is too crowded.

Your advice please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't re-ask that question, it'll be closed as not constructive.

That question was asked in the relatively early days of Stack Overflow, before all the kinks had been worked out.  One change between then and now is that questions asking about open-ended comparisons or pro/con lists are closed because there's not really any *right* answer.

Jeff [wrote about the problem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), providing more insight into why those questions just aren't a good fit.

---

For the general problem of wanting an update on an old question, it's okay to ask a new question if you make clear that you've seen the old question and need a new solution.  Something like:

> I'm having trouble frobbing the widget in my thingamajig.  I've tried to solutions in `<link to old question about widget frobbing>`, but they were written twenty years ago and don't seem to work with the new thingamajig 2.0.  Ideas?

Comment: so where CAN I ask this question? I don't agree with this rule. there is a reason the topic got

Comment: @NahumLitvin Yahoo answers?  ExpertSexChange?  Usenet?  I feel your pain, but just because SO doesn't accept such answers doesn't mean that there's some equally useful and responsive place that does.

Answer (score 0):

If you need updated information because the answers from the question you've noted are not adequate enough (because of differences between VS2008 and VS2012) - ask a new question. It won't be a duplicate, because it's about the different version and the differences are the key factor.

But, if you just think, that the answers are not fully covering the topic, find the topic that is not covered and ask the detailed question.

If you just want to raise more attention because you think that users could write something more, the bounties are the tool you should use. The question is so popular that if something that should be written wasn't written there, it's not propable that someone would write it just because you've asked a new question.