# What do with those answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, obsolete-information

There was a question "[How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/181366)"

The [most popular answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11706/181366) to it says that obsolete answers should be deleted or updated.

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/918066/841064) asked at SO. [Its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920305/841064) became obsolete. Then @michaeltwofish posted [up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395715/841064). Then @Trott made an edit updating original answer.

So currently there are two answers about the same.

Should one of them be deleted? Was it good to update original accepted answer?

**Edit:** Should accepted answer be updated properly (i.e. should

```
Given /^I login successfully$/
  Given "I login with valid credentials"
  Then "I should be logged in"
end
```

be edited to:

```
Given /^I login successfully$/
  step "I login with valid credentials"
  step "I should be logged in"
end
```

?

Comment: Why? If both answers are correct, why should any one of them be deleted?

Comment: If there were only invalid out of date answers, one could argue for deletion. But two good answers are even better than one. ;) Just leave them in place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't delete out-of-date answers!

Quite often I am working with a legacy code base or technology, and I *need* out-of-date answers. I hate it when all I can find are answers that use the latest and greatest technology.

A better solution is to Edit the out-of-date answer to specify that the answer is out of date, and to point to the current way of doing things. This can either be a link to another existing up-to-date answer, or it could be your own up-to-date solution, but regardless of which you chose to do, don't delete the out-of-date part.

Comment: +1, good thing this is exactly what happened.

Comment: I frequently find myself working with legacy code as well, I would love not to have to but the reality is I don't have time to update entire applications to the latest and greatest technologies. There has to a business need for the update to!

Answer (score 0):

**Keep them!**

If you have two good, correct, quality answers why would you delete one of them? As [Bart said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160694/what-do-with-those-answers#comment466142_160694), if they were to invalid answers then one might be deleted. But two good ones? Definitely keep them both.