# Strategy for old technical questions having obsolete answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

I have seen a lot of old questions with great old answers which are up for new answers as technology has evolved.

One such example would be of answers on Android development. A lot has changed since 2010, but there are a lot of old answers to great old questions which needs update.

It's not that users who have answered those questions don't want to update, but it's not possible in case of most questions. This leads to many users with old answers which don’t apply to their current version of same technology.

Can there be a strategy to mark such questions and answers? I am not sure which strategy to be used, but this might certainly benefit our community and reduce duplicacy.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated

Comment: You could start a bounty on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

Comment: Isn't there a better word than *"applicable"*?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q word `up` is applicable in place of `applicable` :-) Edited. Thanks